# Is Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection using singleton concept?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control

In my project's startup file I am using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection so that when an instance is needed, it will be handled by the dependency injection:

```
services.AddTransient<IRepository<Product>, ProductRepository>();
services.AddTransient<IRepository<Order>, OrderRepository>();
```

Is there a way to control whether a new instance or the same instance (singleton) should be returned?

Comment: Yes you can, using AddSingleton - [see here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-3.1)

Comment: Does it support late binding like autofac?

Answer (score 0):

For singleton u can use: (one instance per application lifetime)

```
services.AddSingleton(IRepository<Product>, ProductRepository>()
```

other option is to register as scoped: (one instance per request)

```
services.AddScoped(IRepository<Product>, ProductRepository>()
```